# How to convert TClass to T?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I use RTTI (SuperObject) to convert JSON to object:

```pascal
class function RecordJson.Json2Record<T>(const obj: ISuperObject): T;
var
  ctx: TSuperRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
  try
    Result := ctx.AsType<T>(obj);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I use this way and it works:

```pascal
if aSo.o['TDistanceBhTopConv'] <> nil then
  Result := RecordJson.Json2Record<TDistanceBhTopConv>(aSo.o['TDistanceBhTopConv']);
```

But I have a lot of classes. So I create a `TDictionary` to record the relation of  string and class, and now I want to use the following code:

```pascal
FClassDic: TDictionary<string, TClass>;
FClassDic.Add('TDistanceValTopConv', TDistanceValTopConv);
FClassDic.Add('TDistanceBhTopConv', TDistanceBhTopConv);
FClassDic.Add('TLbXsConv', TLbXsConv);
FClassDic.Add('TConcreteConv', TConcreteConv);
```

```pascal
for Key in FClassDic.Keys do
  if aSo.o[Key] <> nil then
  begin
    Result := RecordJson.Json2Record<FClassDic.Items[Key]>(aSo.o[Key]);
  end;
```

But it can't compile:

> E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Json2Record' that can be called with these arguments

I know this is because of the difference of `TClass` (class of instance) and `T` (instance).

Is there any way to deal this?

Comment: If you have class you can use it to directly construct object instance: `FClassDic.Items[Key].Create` but you will also need to adapt your other code to work with such object directly.

Comment: What you ask is not possible to implement that way. The type parameter of parametrized method must be known at compile time. You can, however, create instance of a class that you retrieve from dictionary as suggested by @DalijaPrasnikar and then call `FromJson` extension method declared by `TSuperObjectHelper`, e.g.: `Result := FClassDic.Items[Key].Create; Result.FromJson(aSo.o[Key]);`.

Comment: If the class types stored in the dictionary have any overridden constructors, storing plain `TClass` (`class of TObject`) will not work, as calling `TClass.Create` won't call those constructors since `TObject.Create` is not `virtual`. So you would need to make the classes derive from a common base class `TBase` that has a `virtual` constructor, then declare a `TBaseClass = class of TBase` type to store in the dictionary, and then you can call `TBaseClass.Create` to create objects and have their constructors called properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a dictionary with object creation procedures, but if it's really worth it...

```
type
  // Object construction function type
  TCreateObjectProc = reference to function(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject;

  // Dictionary specification
  FCreateDict: TDictionary<string, TCreateObjectProc>;
```

Then fill the dictionary with object constructor functions

```
  // Dictionary initialisation
  FCreateDict.Add('TDistanceValTopConv',
    function(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject
    begin
      Result := ctx.AsType<TDistanceValTopConv>(obj);
    end);

  FCreateDict.Add('TDistanceBhTopConv',
    function(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject
    begin
      Result := ctx.AsType<TDistanceBhTopConv>(obj);
    end);

  FCreateDict.Add('TLbXsConv',
    function(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject
    begin
      Result := ctx.AsType<TLbXsConv>(obj);
    end);

  FCreateDict.Add('TConcreteConv',
    function(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject
    begin
      Result := ctx.AsType<TConcreteConv>(obj);
    end);
```

And then use it using

```
  for Key in FCreateDict.Keys do
    if aSo.o[Key] <> nil then
    begin
      ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
      try
        Result := FCreateDict.Items[Key](ctx, aSo.o[Key]);
      finally
        ctx.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

And when using the `TSerializer<T: class>` class of Remy:

```pascal
type
  TSerializer<T: class> = class
  public
    class function Deserialize(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject;
  end;

class function TSerializer<T>.Deserialize(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext;
  obj: ISuperObject): TObject;
begin
  Result := ctx.AsType<T>(obj);
end;
```

Then the code regarding the dictionary initialization looks like this (which compiles using Delphi 10.3)

```pascal
  FCreateDict.Add('TDistanceValTopConv', TSerializer<TDistanceValTopConv>.Deserialize);
  FCreateDict.Add('TDistanceBhTopConv', TSerializer<TDistanceBhTopConv>.Deserialize);
  FCreateDict.Add('TLbXsConv', TSerializer<TLbXsConv>.Deserialize);
  FCreateDict.Add('TConcreteConv', TSerializer<TConcreteConv>.Deserialize);
```

Comment: You should be able to simplify that repetitive code using a Generic function, eg: `type TSerializer<T: class> = class public class function Deserialize(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject; end;` `class function TSerializer<T>.Deserialize(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject; begin Result := ctx.AsType<T>(obj); end;` then you can do `FCreateDict.Add('TDistanceValTopConv', TDeserializer<TDistanceValTopConv>.Deserialize); ...`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it compile error ```E2010 Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'T'```in
```class function TSerializer<T>.Deserialize(const ctx: TSuperRttiContext; obj: ISuperObject): TObject; begin Result := ctx.AsType<T>(obj); end;```

Comment: @Para in RHoek's example, you are not getting the error with `TDistanceValTopConv`, `TDistanceBhTopConv`, or `TLbXsConv`, only with `TConcreteConv`?  Does `TConcreteConv` derive from `TObject`?

Comment: @R. Hoek yes, it is work, but why i create a dict is I have a lot of classes, in your code, i must write TCreateObjectProc for everyone.maybe The most original code is  simpler and easier to read?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, R. Hoek code can run.My point is that he made the code more complicated, let the code more less and simple, You did what i wanted, but it compile error. Can you give more ideas?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I know this code does not look very nice, but since I don’t know the exact specifications, I tried something which could use a dictionary in the same way Para is doing in the example. But I was only given a abstract sample of what I thought should work...